# What does # represent in the current dart

Tags: dart

Previously #time referred to an element id in a query. However, this was replaced in current Dart with $['time']. Yet I see # being used still. What does # now refers to in the current Dart release?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`$` is a property of `PolymerElement`. It's a mapping of ids to Nodes for children in the shadow tree with id attributes.

It's basically a direct shortcut for `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#$id')`.

http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/polymer/Polymer.html#$

Answer (score 2):

Used in [querySelector](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html.html#querySelector) ( like `querySelector('#myId')` ) it's used to refer to an element id ( this is [the CSS id Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors) ).

Used directly inside Dart code, `#id` is a synonym for `const Symbol('id')` ( see [Symbols section of the specification language](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.qke6yiz8c62q) ). This is really useful when you deal with *dart:mirrors*.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. querySelector('#myId') is now deprecated though in favour of $['myId']?

Comment: $['myId'] notation only works within PolymerElements. It is not generally part of dart:html or the language itself. See: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/polymer/Polymer.html#$